# Activity_main.xml-Preview is not available

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, preview

The `activity_main.xml`-Preview is not available. How can I enable it? (I know, it's a nooby question)
[image]

Comment: can u explain a little more ? and maybe add your code so everyone can understand and help you better

Comment: Clean and rebuild your App...

Answer (score 0):

Try with these normal stuffs..might help

Change the API version in preview panel.

Check your XML namespace.

Try refreshing preview panel.

Comment: Actually from your description unable to find what's wrong!